# What is the simplest way to expand a slice to its capacity?

Tags: go, slice

I have a program that uses a buffer pool to reduce allocations in a few performance-sensitive sections of the code.

Something like this: [play link](https://play.golang.org/p/c_gsqBcbE-)

```
// some file or any data source
var r io.Reader = bytes.NewReader([]byte{1,2,3})

// initialize slice to max expected capacity
dat := make([]byte, 20)

// read some data into it. Trim to length.
n, err := r.Read(dat)
handle(err)
dat = dat[:n]

// now I want to reuse it: 
for len(dat) < cap(dat) {
        dat = append(dat, 0) 
}

log.Println(len(dat))
// add it to free list for reuse later
// bufferPool.Put(dat)
```

I always allocate fixed length slices, which are guaranteed to be larger than the maximum size needed. I need to reduce size to the actual data length to use the buffer, but I also need it to be the maximum size again to read into it the next time I need it.

The only way I know of to expand a slice is with `append`, so that is what I am using. The loop feels super dirty though. And potentially inefficient. My benchmarks show it isn't horrible, but I feel like there has to be a better way.

I know only a bit about the internal representation of slices, but if I could only somehow override the length value without actually adding data, it would be really nice. I don't really need to zero it out or anything.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

"Extending" a slice to its capacity is simply a [slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions), and specify the capacity as the high index. The high index does not need to be less than the length. The restriction is:

> For arrays or strings, the indices are in range if `0 <= low <= high <= len(a)`, otherwise they are out of range. **For slices, the upper index bound is the slice capacity `cap(a)`** rather than the length.

Example:

```
b := make([]byte, 10, 20)
fmt.Println(len(b), cap(b), b)

b = b[:cap(b)]
fmt.Println(len(b), cap(b), b)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KL6Ag5smNt)):

```
10 20 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
20 20 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: Wow, I feel silly now. I swear I tried that and got out of bounds or something. But it does indeed work, as long as you stay under the capacity.

Answer (score 9):

You can expand a slice to its capacity with slicing:

```
s = s[:cap(s)]
```

Answer (score -1):

> Using ***built-in*** `copy` & `append` func, many operations can be done on top of this.

See: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#expand