# Why the standard library bufio.Read(p []byte) (int, err) checks len(p) instead of cap(p) in Go

Tags: go

The function writes up to `len(p)` to `p`, so `p` must have some dummy content before the call and the content will be overwritten after the call.
If this understanding is right, why doesn't the function use and check `cap(p)`?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're asking a question about some third-party code, you should provide a permalink to that code.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart the question is about the standard library.

Comment: @hobbs I understand. But a) it would be much more convenient for readers and b) that standard library code changes over time, hence my request for a permalink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply the `Read` method's **task** is to read `len(p)` byte(s) to the **underlying array** and return **the number of bytes read**, and the error. So it has nothing to do with `cap(p)`.

1. TLDR: It is **by design** (The bytes are taken from at most one Read on the underlying Reader):
   From `go/src/bufio/bufio.go`:

```
// Read reads data into p.
// It returns the number of bytes read into p.
// The bytes are taken from at most one Read on the underlying Reader,
// hence n may be less than len(p).
// To read exactly len(p) bytes, use io.ReadFull(b, p).
// At EOF, the count will be zero and err will be io.EOF.
func (b *Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
```

Yes, it is possible to use `cap(p)`,  and read `cap(p)` instead of `len(p)`, but it is another **design choice** with its **trade-offs** (e.g.: instead of re-slicing you may need to use **memory allocation** for every and each call), since it returns the number of bytes read, the caller may use re-slicing to send length needed to the `Read` method. [Try it](https://play.golang.org/p/tNzwRIdZ_os):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    p := make([]byte, 0, 4)
    n := read(p)
    p = p[:n]
    fmt.Println(len(p), cap(p)) // 4 4
    fmt.Println(p)              // [0 0 0 4]
}
func read(p []byte) int {
    n := cap(p)
    p = p[:n]
    p[n-1] = 4
    return n
}
```

---

2. The `p` is a slice and **pass by value** and the `Read` method can **not** change the **length** or the **capacity** of the `p` inside the method and sent it back to the outside world (unless you change the method signature to either `Read(p *[]byte)` or `Read(p []byte) []byte`).
   In `func (b *Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {`
   The `p []byte` means the `p` is a slice of `byte` so `p` itself is a data structure containing a pointer to the underlying array and a length and a capacity of that array.
   This method is not allowed to change the **capacity** and **length** of `p`, imagine `p` has length of 0 and you need to change it to 4 (see [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46346077/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-expand-a-slice-to-its-capacity)). Since the `p` outside of the method is a **different variable** than the `p` inside the method, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/5Yk1G67NzH0), see the output (see comments). The `p` address is `0xc00000c080` inside and `0xc00000c060` at the outside - so it is a different variable):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    p := make([]byte, 0, 4)
    fmt.Println(len(p), cap(p)) // 0 4
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &p)      // 0xc00000c060

    read(p)

    fmt.Println(len(p), cap(p)) // 0 4
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &p)      // 0xc00000c060

    fmt.Println(p)
}
func read(p []byte) {
    fmt.Println(len(p), cap(p)) // 0 4
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &p)      // 0xc00000c080
    p = p[:cap(p)]
    fmt.Println(len(p), cap(p)) // 4 4
    fmt.Println(p)              // [0 0 0 0]
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &p)      // 0xc00000c080
}
```

---

3. Thanks to @Brits:
   Another benefit of the approach taken is that you can allocate a large backing array i.e. `a := make([]byte,0,BIGSIZE)` and then use the one buffer in multiple calls to Read without the need for re-allocations (`n, _ := read(a[0:4]` or `n,_ = read(a[n:n+2]`). If Read did use the capacity you would need to allocate a buffer of the precise size needed for every call.

Comment: I would just add that a large benefit of the approach taken is that you can allocate a large backing array i.e. `a := make([]byte,0,BIGSIZE)` and then use the one buffer in multiple calls to `Read` without the need for reallocations (`n, _ := read(a[0:4]; n,_ = read(a[n:n+2]`). If `Read` did use the capacity you would need to allocate a buffer of the precise size needed for every call.

Comment: In item 2, I think you meant to say that `Read` can't change `len(p)` (it's true that it can't change `cap(p)` either, but so what? :-) )...

Comment: Right, I just meant to suggest the edit you made in version 4. Reslicing length is older than reslicing capacity, and Read is of that age.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first part of your question, Go by default initializes its variables with their corresponding zero-values, so yes the slice will have some content for `len(p)`.

But, note that the `bufio.Read` method using `len(p)` has no connection with this.
A slice *length* defines the memory the particular slice can use. Just because it has more storage *capacity* doesn't mean that it should be allowed to do so, it's just idiomatic go and quite reasonable.

Take for instance a slice of length 5 and capacity 8:

```
a := make([]int, 5, 8)
```

Now, if you try to access some element out of the scope of slice length, say the 7th element by doing

```
fmt.Println(a[6])                 <<<------ Gives error
```

You will get an `index out of range` panic.

Also, it may be helpful to know that `slice` is an abstraction over the Go's array type and is declared as

```
type slice struct {
    array unsafe.Pointer
    len   int
    cap   int
}
```

in the [runtime package](https://golang.org/src/runtime/slice.go#:%7E:text=type%20slice%20struct) and that length is an inherent property of a slice datatype.

Answer (score 1):

It is conventional in Go to use the slice length `len(p)` to specify the  number of available elements in a slice's backing array.  The Read method follows this convention.